# PHP Facebook return my own photos and videos

Tags: php, facebook

I used to run a web page that would take all my own photos from Facebook and display them in categories.

Now that Facebook has removed user_photos and user_videos from the login, it won't anymore work.

Is there anyway to get my own photos and videos without submitting the app to the AppReview? I only need access to my own photos, not others'.

Best,

Comment: This question should probably belong on the Facebook help boards, but whatever. Don't take this for granted, but I expect you can't. Especially since the GDPR and the Cambridge Analytica incident.

Comment: Only if you leave your app in dev mode. But then the rate limits are more strict, I think, so you would need proper caching.

Comment: @CBroe I had just tried dev mode before your comment and it instantly hit the limit.